# jQuery - getting an element by class via parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a wrapper div and inside a button and a hidden div. When pushing the button the div shall be displayed. I don't want to use ids because the construction apears several times on the webpage. What is the right jquery command?

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acN6R/4/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">

   <div class="button"> see more </div>
   <div class="moreInfos"> Lorem ipsum... </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.moreInfos{ display: none;}
```

jQuery

```
    $(".wrapp").on('click', '.button', function(){

    $(this).parent('.moreInfos').css('display', 'block');
});
```

Comment: Is `.wrapp` a typo? In your HTML you only have `.wrap`.

Comment: you have a typo as `diplay`.. its `display`.. updated in my answer too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the click event is bound to the button:

```
$(this).parent().find(".moreInfos").show();
```

if the click event is bound to the wrapping div:

```
$(this).find(".moreInfos").show();
```

**FIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/BeNdErR/acN6R/8/

Answer (score 4):

You were very close. Use `parent().find()`

```
$(this).parent().find('.moreInfos').css('display', 'block');
```

Also, you have a type `$(".wrapp") extra 'p'.. just`$(".wrap")`

You also have a typo here: not `diplay`, its `display`

***[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/acN6R/14/)***

Comment: This will not work since `this` is the button, not the wrapper.

Answer (score -1):

Try using [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
$(".wrap").on('click', '.button', function(){

    $(this).siblings('.moreInfos').show();
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/acN6R/5/